# Monitor memory usage of each node in a slurm job

Tags: slurm

My slurm job uses several nodes, and I want to know the maximum memory usage of each node for a running job. What can I do?

Right now, I can ssh into each node and do `free -h -s 30 > memory_usage`, but I think there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The Slurm accounting will give you the maximum memory usage over time over all tasks directly. If that information is not sufficient, you can setup profiling following [this documentaiton](https://slurm.schedmd.com/hdf5_profile_user_guide.html) and you will receive from Slurm the full memory usage of each process as a time series for the duration of the job. You can then aggregate per node, find the maximum, etc.